# Batch check for special Characters

Tags: batch-file

How can I check in a Batch File for special Characters like "!" ">" "<"  "  "|" ? I've already tried it with:

`if "%Letter%"=="!" echo Yes`
`if ["%Letter%"]==["!"] echo Yes`

But nothing of that worked

Comment: The first variant works and is best practice; it might fail when the strings contain quotes on their own (like `&"&"`, for example); use [delayed expansion](http://sste.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for a variant robust against all special cases...

Comment: This has been answered a few times. You can do something like this with delayed expansion enabled. `echo !letter!| findstr /i "[^a-z0-9-]" >NUL && echo special characters.`

Comment: Still doesnt work. It says "Syntax error"

Comment: How did you test it? When it says "Syntax error". Did you test with `"` as letter? With delayed expansion `if "!letter!"=="^!"` it can't say "Syntax error"

Comment: Now it doesnt says "Syntax error" but it detect it as a comma ",".
Its actually for an encryption progranm

Comment: You should show more of your code, to decide how it can be improved